# Saving RelativeLayout as bitmap

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to save a `RelativeLayout` as a `bitmap` and insert it into the gallery, the code below throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:282)
        at maa.Fragements.ColorPaletteFragment.galleryAddPic(ColorPaletteFragment.java:344)
```

because the parameter `imagePath` of `galleryAddPic` method is *empty* or *null*

insert Image to gallery:

```
 private void galleryAddPic(String imagePath) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(imagePath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

saving the image:

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public class saveViewAsBitmap extends AsyncTask<RelativeLayout, String, String> {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            txt.setText("Saving image to gallery ...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(RelativeLayout... relatives) {
            String savedImagePath = null;
            String imageFileName = "inColor" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
            Bitmap image = getBitmapFromView(relatives[0]);
            File storageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                            + "/inColor Folder");
            boolean success = true;
            if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                success = storageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            if (success) {
                File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
                savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
                try {
                    OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dialogLoading.dismiss();
            }
            return savedImagePath;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String path) {
            super.onPostExecute(path);
            galleryAddPic(path);
        }
    }
```

can anyone help me to get resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in Manifest file